# set default file open path in electron application

Tags: javascript, html, windows, electron

How to set the default path in electron app that is used whenever users select files to upload (via HTML file inputs)?

Context:
I have a website running in an electron application where users can upload and download files. Whenever users download files the save-dialog shows the default location. This is achieved by setting: `browserWindow.webContents.session.setDownloadPath(myDefaultPath)`.

How could I do the same for the open-dialog? There is no `setFileOpenPath()` or similar.

Note: The open dialog is opened via `<input type="file" ...>` and *not* via the electron dialog. The download dialog is opened via file-saver-es if that matters.

Now in theory I could intercept the "select file"-button's click event and send an ipc message to the electron main process and open an electron dialog where I have control over the path. Then load the selected file and send the blob back via ipc to the website (renderer process). This seems awfully complicated for what I need. Hence the question.

Comment: You cannot do this with an `<input>` element. The best use of Electron isn't plopping a preexisting web site into it - as you're discovering. You lose the advantage of having access to the platform.

Comment: I get your point. But I don't see a technical limitation that would prevent the BrowserWindow (i.e. chrome) to provide such a functionality. It's basically the same as setting the default download path.

Comment: well if you are looking for a _technical limitation_, that would be [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) - which provides no avenue to carry out such action.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I'm not saying the <input> element should provide such functionality. I'm saying the electron BrowserWindow should (let me set the default globally).

Comment: This "_The open dialog is opened via <input type="file" ...>_" - which is a Chromium thing - not technically an Electron thing. So, if you want to delve into the bleeding edge, you can use the [FileSystem API]() which allows the use of [showOpenFilePicker](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#api-showopenfilepicker) which takes a [FIlePickerOptions](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#dictdef-filepickeroptions) object with a property named, aptly `startIn`. [This article](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) should help. Are you sure you don't want to use the Electron Dialog :-)

Comment: Nice, I will definitely have a look at this!